# How to change Bootstrap toggle navigation color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

From what I see this is the code for the toggle-navigation button:

```
<button id="nav-toggle-button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

I added id="nav-toggle-button" and gave it this CSS:

```
#nav-toggle-button {
color: gray;
}
```

but nothing has changed. I tried adding !important as well, without success and I don't know what else to try. Anybody knows?

EDIT: Here's a fiddle with a solution suggested by Prashant123 (sorry, not enough reputation to vote up your answer!): http://jsfiddle.net/LuKSB/1/  it's way better already, but it would be perfect if the horizontal lines inside the button would be visible (white). I guess it would be changing the color, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to change the text color? Or the background color? Because the color property applies to the text color, not the background color.

Comment: With the update I have the background color covered, now I think it's about text color.

Answer (score 13):

**Changes for Bootstrap 4**

The `navbar-toggler-icon` in Bootstrap 4 uses an SVG `background-image`. There are 2 versions of the toggler icon image. One for a light navbar, and one for a dark (inverse) navbar...

```
// this is a black icon with 50% opacity
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;..");
}
// this is a white icon with 50% opacity
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;..");
}
```

If you want to change the color of this image to something else, you can customize the icon. For example, here I set the RGB value to pink (255,102,203). Notice the `stroke='rgba(255,102,203, 0.5)'` value in the SVG data..

```
.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,102,203, 0.5)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

**Demo** http://codeply.com/go/4FdZGlPMNV

Comment: Nice!

Note for anyone using hex color values: you will need to encode your `#` as `%23`, as `#` is a reserved value in urls.

Answer (score 2):

try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4PQLQ/1/)
**html**

```
<button id="nav-toggle-button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

**css**

```
#nav-toggle-button{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it worked, I tried that before without success, maybe there was a typo. It's close to what I want though I need the lines (icon?) in the button to be white (see my edited question).

Comment: New Bootstrap 4 uses svg factor image for the toggler icon.
To make this for example white instead of grey:
`.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)' stroke-width='3' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Prashant's example you can target the span's color specifically by changing the CSS input to:

```
#nav-toggle-button span {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @zim I add this in css changing the stroke color rgba:

```
.navbar-light button.navbar-toggler.collapsed span.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(108, 99, 255, 1)' stroke-width='3' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

This is the color when 'collapsed', if you want add a color when the hamburger is not collapsed, first, in the button, you need to add a class 'collapsed', because this class is added only after the first clic, and then, in the css style file, you need to add the same code with differend stroke color without the class collapsed like this:

```
.navbar-light button.navbar-toggler span.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(253, 92, 99, 1)' stroke-width='3' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```